# Extracting Vue component props as a type

Tags: typescript, vue.js, es6-modules

I have a few Vue components and I wish to extract the props from such component and use them as a type instead of a value. I have another component whereas I would like to take in a prop which is an array of another component's props like such.

```js
props: {
    links: Array<CardLink>
}
```

I have tried forgoing having individual props and creating a custom class outlining the values I want inside my component (This being in reference to the CardLink component) and then taking in the values in a class instance bound to a prop name as such.

```js
export class CardLink {
    text: string;
    url: string;

    constructor(text: string, url: string) {
        this.text = text;
        this.url = url;
    }
}

export default {
    props: {
        content: {type: CardLink, required: true}
    }
}
```

How can I bring `content` to the top of my scope so I won't have to type `content` each time I wish to access a attribute?

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Where's the question in this question?

Comment: Apologies, it seems such part didn't get posted. My question is in regards to pulling "content" to the top of the scope so I won't be required to prefix each of my attribute accessing attempts with "content". I will edit the original question to reflect my actual question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies, I ended up finding the solution to be as simple as deconstructing `content` inside my `data()` function like so.

```js
data() {
    return {
        ...this.content,
    }
}
```

which will allow you to access the attributes. Thanks!